# UITableView only shows one cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, jailbreak

So, I am writing a jailbreak tweak, and it uses a UITableView. The method that my class `AscendCustomTableCell` has just adds stuff to the view.

So, the problem is that the table view only shows the latest notification. For example, if I get a text, it works fine, but then if I get another text, the first one goes away, and the second one comes in at the second cell on the table view.

Every time a notification comes in, I add it to the array of notifications, and then I reload the table view. Why doesn't the old cell stay?

**Code:**

```
@interface AscendTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation AscendTableViewDelegate

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //[cell grabFromBBBulletin:[activeLockScreenNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath]];
    AscendCustomTableCell *cell = [ascendNotificationTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notifTableCell"];
        [cell grabFromBBBulletin:[activeLockScreenNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AscendCustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"notifTableCell"];
    }
    //[cell trashOldLabels];
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [activeLockScreenNotifications count];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return 85;
}

@end
```

Comment: Dont use your custom notifications array as a reliable datasource for your tableview. Look elsewhere to store your data array, perhaps NSUserDefaults as a basic start.

Comment: It needs to be an array, it's an array of BBBulliten's. I get the information from them.

Comment: I know it needs to be an array, you can store arrays in the method I suggested above. The reason I say this is because notifications go away/disappear into thin air once activated. :)

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that the data source your old cell is pointing to is probably being released. So when you reload the table the old cell is updating itself with a pointer to a released object. When a new notification comes in you need to copy the contents to your own data source (array of object). Simply create an `NSMutableArray` property or ivar on your class and copy the data over then reload the table view using your own data source.